# I can't send a file from my server filesystem to the client (downloading with the Save As dialog box)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webclient

I am working with some calculations and the product of my business logic is the creation of a PDF report (C# ASP.NET). So far, I have managed to create the report. The convention of my company is storing all the data in .gz format somewhere in the filesystem. At the click of some button, I need to send the file to the client, with the opening of the dialog box for downloading and saving the file to the desired destination.

I have tried a lot of options, including .TransmitFile, .OutputStream.Write as they are the methods that the Response object has. However, I'm not getting any feedback back. There doesn't seem to be any errors and the code is running as the methods never happened. If I set a try catch block, the code runs into an exception with description "Thread was aborted", though I heard that Response.End always throws an exception.

```
var file = new FileInfo(integrityCheckInfo.ReportPath);
var buffer = integrityCheckInfo.ReportData;
//Code for downloading the report, doesn't work, and I don't know how to fix this.

if (File.Exists(integrityCheckInfo.ReportPath))
{
    Response.Clear();
//Response.AddHeader("Accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/x-gzip";
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Expires = -1000;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.gz");
//Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
//Response.Flush();
//Response.TransmitFile(integrityCheckInfo.ReportPath);
//Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}
```

The code that starts with // are comments and they are not included in this iteration where I wanted to download the .gz instead of the PDF but also got nothing for feedback.

Comment: Your code worked for me. The ReportData I used was simply "test".  Maybe swap out var buffer = integrityCheckInfo.ReportData; for var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test"); to see if that works. If it does, at least it'll narrow down where the problem resides.

Comment: Is the file name always `report.gz` (one word)?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue but just in case, change `Response.AddHeader` to `Response.AppendHeader` so you're not overwriting anything.